# How to convert a geometry data string to degrees?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

The query SELECT geom FROM myLayer; I get a 2 kilometres long string in a table, which I wish I could convert it to radians values to handle them later on. this is an example of what I get:

```
"01060000000100000001030000000100000005000000000070AC9FB81841000053BF535551410000303295B8184100001A6053555141000060FE8EB818410000670654555141000090399AB8184100004C6854555141000070AC9FB81841000053BF53555141"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is a representation of how PostGIS internally stores a geometry.  You need to use something like ST_AsText or ST_ASEWKT (see http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html )

So, for you example, 
`SELECT ST_ASEWkt(geom) FROM myLayer;`

To get it in radians, what I'd probably do is project it to a decimal degrees datum (i.e. WGS84), peel off the x and y coordinates separately and convert them (assuming this is point geometry here).  So, for example:
`SELECT ST_X(ST_Transform(geom, 4326))*3.14/180, ST_Y(ST_Transform(geom,4326))*3.15/180 FROM myLayer;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have projected coordinates, and you want to provide geographic (unprojected) coordinates. I'm willing to bet you want degrees and not radians, so a common target SRID is 4326. Use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to reproject the data:

```
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4326) AS geom_in_degrees
FROM your_table;
```

Note that an SRID should be set for the source geometry column. If not, then there are problems.

---

On a further theoretical note, to convert coordinates of degrees to radians (I've never seen this!), you can scale the coordinates from the origin at (0,0) by a factor of π/180. This can be done using an affine transformation function, or it's helper [ST_Scale](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Scale.html):

```
SELECT ST_Scale(
         ST_SetSRID(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), 0),
         pi()/180.0, pi()/180.0) AS geom_in_radians
FROM your_table;;
```